# How to automate PowerPoint spell-check?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have searched high and low to find some way to try to automate spell-check in VBA for PowerPoint, but have not been able to uncover anything. I'm looking for similar functionality to what Word and Excel offer in automating spell-check, but for PowerPoint

The routine I'm after would be like (psuedo):

```
For Each Mispelling in ActivePresentation.Mispellings
    Mispelling.IgnoreAll = True
Next
ActivePresentation.Save
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hahaha...isn't that the point :)

Comment: Does the below answer your question?

Comment: Yes! It's unfortunate that it can't though :(

Answer (score 2):

Progammatically checking spelling in PowerPoint is not available. It's rather unfortunate as I've needed this myself before too (to bulk spell-check multiple PPTs programmatically). At best you could interop with Word and send the text there to be spell-checked and then send back to PowerPoint, but I image this would be rather clunky.